# Dynamic Source: Excel Connection SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis

Here's what I'm doing:

I'm using a Foreach Loop container to grab any .xlsx files in a specified folder and assigning the fully qualified name to a variable called FileName.

Then I have a data flow with an Excel source importing to an OLE DB Destination.

How do I make the excel source the FileName variable?

--When I create the same process for flat files I have no problems creating an expression and changing the delay validation to true but when I try excel files it doesn't work the same. I've been able to work around the problem by using a file system task to move the xlsx files to a new folder giving it a static name and importing from that file, but I'm tired of doing that. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for [Dynamically assign filename to excel connection string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536719/dynamically-assign-filename-to-excel-connection-string)

Comment: I feel like an idiot now because I have tried that countless times but because there was the red x on the Excel source I never tried actually running the job. Today I got frustrated and ran it anyway with it setup like the link you provided and it works. Thanks.