# SSIS dts_e_oledberror when using excel connection with expression

Tags: excel, ssis

In SSIS when I create a connection manager to a specific file, all works ok, but when I try to put in an expression into the connection manager to point to a folder instead of a specific file name (ExcelFilePath mapped to a local variable), I'm getting dts_e_oledberror and a red X to the Excel source box into Data Flow.

When I go into the Excel source box, then at the Name of the Excel sheet: No tables or views could be loaded.

Any ideas how to restolve this, please?

Comment: There are 2 possible issues. 1. Check the variable that the filename exists. 2. Check the file exists in the folder that you have in the variable.

Comment: 1. Done in the Control flow via a C# script box. 2. 2. Done with the same C# box. The problem is, when I try to parameterize the Excel file into a folder only, then I'm getting the error message. Unless what do you mean by Check the variable that the filename exists?

Comment: Path + Filename ... `C:\TestFolder\SomeExcelFile.xlsx`

Comment: Just tested, unfortunately that didn't work. What I tried to do is create a file like you recommended but with 1 data line only, point the connection manager to that file, and keep the parameter to the path. The red X error message was gone, the package run without error, but processed only 1 line, so it's a fail for me. Any other ideas, or how do I do this setup exactly, please?

Comment: Just to be more specific, the file name always changes (the date at the end of the file name, to be moer precise), and every day, there is just 1 file in the input folder, and I'd like to pick up the file automatically.

Comment: As I understand is that you have a task to retrieve path + filename `c:\testfolder\somefile_20141008.xlsx` into a variable. The variable is referenced by Excel Connection Manager. Then the error does not matter as long as your task concatenates the Path + Filename correctly into the variable.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it's setup: variable = path + filename. This case: MyExcelFile19000101.xlsx this is where I point the connection manager. When I try to parameterize, then it should pick up the real file (from the parameterized file name): MyExcelFile20140921.xlsx. When I parameterize the connection manager I get a red X on the ExcelSource box and wipes out the table name (the workseet name from excel file), OLE DB error. If I don't parameterize the connection manager, then it still processes 19000101.xls instead of 20140921.xls. Any help, please?

Comment: Compare your implementation to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536719/dynamically-assign-filename-to-excel-connection-string/21536893#21536893 I suspect you need to specify that the Connection Manager should `DelayValidate = True`

Comment: @HenrikS .. billinkc is correct. You need to set `DelayValidate = True`.

Comment: I tried that, then I can run the package, but for some strange reason still processing only the wrong file MyExcelFile19000101.xlsx instead of MyExcelFile20140921.xlsx and when I check some logs (email myself the variable value in the subject), the variable is set correctly. Is it working for you guys, can you reproduce the case?