# Modify excel connection strings like SqlConnectionStringBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssis

I would like to modify connection strings for excel very much like how `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` works.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcelFile.xlsx;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";
```

I tried to use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` but it's not working. It says "keyword not supported".

How do I modify this kind of connection string with ease?

Comment: You might need the [OleDbConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead

Answer (score 0):

The easiest place to change this is Excel Connection Manager's `ExcelFilePath` property.

[image]

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536719/dynamically-assign-filename-to-excel-connection-string)