# SSIS Dynamically Import Excel Files

Tags: excel, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

So I created a ForEach loop and a data flow task to write from Excel to SQL DB. All works fine with the Excel source hard coded. As soon as I change the connection string to use the file path variable as a data source, I get this error:

> [Excel Source [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXoE3.png)] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager 1" failed with error code 0xC0202009.

I print the file path in a message box before executing the data flow so I know that the variable is working.

[image]

[image]

Naturally I browsed tons of answers and tutorials, but nothing. Here's what I tried:

- Changing the data source on the connection string
- Using the ExcelFilePath expression instead of the connection string
- Changing the Excel file name in the connection manager properties
- Ran the package in 32 bits
- Set delayed validation to True in all data flow tasks and connection manager
- Deleting and creating a new connection manager
- Combinations of the above, lots of trial an error

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

I'd appreciate your help as I've been plucking my hair all afternoon with this :)

Comment: It sounds like you are missing the expression of setting the foreach enumerator to filename on the connection manager

Comment: Also, "Connection string" which is different than "Excel File Path" if you are only updating the path use the later

Comment: I cover using expressions with Excel files in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21536893/181965)

Comment: change property delay validation.

Comment: @billinkc I read your fantastic answer, unfortunately it didn't work. I came across it before posting this question and tried using the excel file path. I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got this to work, so I imported the Excel files to the DB using SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Test\Excel_Data.xlsx;', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

https://www.sqlshack.com/query-excel-data-using-sql-server-linked-servers/