# SSIS dynamic excel read

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, expression, connection-string

I have been trying to read multiple excel files through SSIS from a shared location and i get two error messages.

1. Error at FileLoopingTest [Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"]: The connection string components cannot contain unquoted semicolons. If the value must contain a semicolon, enclose the entire value in quotes. This error occurs when values in the connection string contain unquoted semicolons, such as the InitialCatalog property.

*Expression:  "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+@[User::varFileName]+";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES\";"*

2. The result of the expression ""Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+@[User::varFileName]+";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES\";"" on property "\Package.Connections[Excel Connection Manager].Properties[ExcelFilePath]" cannot be written to the property. The expression was evaluated, but cannot be set on the property.

Any inputs would be great.

Thanks

Comment: **Please provide also what causes the error, do some debugging, show us your code.** What you posted here hardly tells us anything.

Comment: I find I have better success working with the ExcelFilePath property instead of modifying the full ConnectionString property https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536719/dynamically-assign-filename-to-excel-connection-string/21536893#21536893

Comment: What does the output of the expression give you?  Take what the expression results would be and put them directly in he connection manager and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

pls try
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+@[User::varFileName]+";Extended Properties=\""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES\";"";"